# Why isn't my javascript function defined for this function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is very consistent, but firebug is showing that my saveForm function is not being defined form my 'button.save' event handler, but it works for my 'button.deleteForm' event handler:

```
    function saveForm(form)
    {

        var $form = form;
        var url = $form.attr('action');

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               enctype: 'mutipart/form-data',
               url: url,
               data: $form.serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
               success: function(data)
               {
                    // data is the server response.
                    // change this function to tell the
                    // user whether their submission 
                    // is correct or what fields have
                    // bad data.
                    var response = JSON.parse(data);
                    return true;
               }
             });
        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    }

    // Do not use event handlers like .click(). This is the
    // only viable solution for handling events on dynamically
    // generated HTML elements. This handles the saving of data
    // to the server.
    $(document).on('click', 'button.save', function(e){
        var $form = $(this).closest('form'); 
        saveForm(form);            
    });

    // This event handler is responsible for deleting data.
    // For Joey's job: Please make sure that this calls save
    // after the user hits delete. This will save the data in
    // the database.
    $(document).on('click', 'button.deleteForm', function(e){

        // Get the form to update before deleting our embedded form
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var str = $(this).attr('id');

        // Get the table id in review to delete
        var deleteForm = str + '_review';
        $('table#' + deleteForm).remove();

        // Get the collection form id to delete
        var idArray = str.split('_');
        idArray.pop();
        divId = '#' + idArray.join('_');
        $(divId).remove();

        saveForm($form);
    });
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to pass `$form` instead of `form`?

Comment: No, it actually doesn't matter since js is loosely typed.

Comment: Note AJAX is *asynchronous* usually so returning from `success` does nothing for you.

Comment: i think you will find that it does matter. saveForm(form); should be saveForm($form);

Comment: @Mr.Student — Dynamic typing doesn't mean that you can change a variable name in just one of the places that you use it and have things continue to work.

Comment: m90, nvm I I didn't realize I was missing the $ when I defined it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you missed `$` in saveform

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.save', function(e){
    var $form = $(this).closest('form'); 
    saveForm($form);  
     //------^----here          
});
```

Comment: This is a problem, but the question is asking about why `saveForm` is undefined.

Comment: i think `saveForm()` is defined.. but since the argument passed is not correct, OP is getting error there (which made OP think,the function is undefined)..but incase of `button.deleteForm` the argument is proper so no error.. just a guess though.. :).. and i don't see any reason here for that function to be undefined..